# wpf net 4.5 System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush to System.Windows.Media.Brush

Tags: wpf, solidcolorbrush

Strange question , does not affect operation .

Severity    Count   Data Context    Binding Path    Target  Target Type Description File    Line    Project
Error   8   SevenSegmentControl, Name='SevenSegmentUserControl' NumberColor Path.Fill, Name='top'   Brush   Cannot convert from type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'. Consider setting a converter on the binding.

https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/Download.aspx?file=/KB/WPF/319495/SevenSegmentSource.zip&rp=https://www.codeproject.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change to Mode=OneWay, no error msg. (you dont need to use the 2ways)

```
    <Style x:Key="PathStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding NumberColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="EllipseStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding ColonColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
```